# ActiveRecord - :belongs_to multiple classes. Reconfiguring behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, configuration, has-many, belongs-to

I have built the following but without using the Rails Model. 
I have following models without any specified relations to each other. 
Tale
Purpose
Culture
Moral
Value
Book
Keyword
Character

I am manually storing all the relationship info as arrays in a single relations table with structure as follows
[image: for is the table name / model name pluralized and for_id is the object id]

What I would like to do is something like this - 
    Model: 
    Tale -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Purpose -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Culture -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Morals -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Values -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Books -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Keywords -> has_many: :tale_relations
    Characters -> has_many: :tale_relations

```
Model: TaleRelation ->
belongs_to: :tale
belongs_to: :purpose
belongs_to: :culture
belongs_to: :morals
belongs_to: :values
belongs_to: :books
belongs_to: :keywords
belongs_to: :characters
```

But would not like the tale_relations table to have multiple columns for each of these different models
I mean i do not want tale_id, purpose_id, moral_id and so on (8 such columns)
Want to be able to identify the records through the table name (:for column) and id # (:for_id column).

currently it is working manually, but just thought the code code really become clean and simple and actually extendible if i can get this working. with just two columns any relationship can be identified.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem may become a lot easier if you impose additional structure on your models. The fact that you call your model TaleRelation makes me think that most of these things should be directly related tale, which could be done with a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship, then other things could be related [through: :tale](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). But I think we can also solve the question as stated.

First, you want to look at [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). In the code you posted above, the first step would be to use `belongs_to :relatable, polymorphic: true` in TaleRelation, and `has_many :tale_relations, as: :relatable` in your other models. This requires that the tale_relations table have the two columns relatable_id and relatable_type, which is what you're trying to do with for and for_id.

However I think you really want to take this one step further and also get rid of the tales, characters, values, etc columns. We can do this using two polymorphic relationships instead of just the one.

First, the table structure (4 columns):

```
create_table :tale_relations do |t|
  t.integer :relater_id
  t.string :relater_type
  t.integer :relatee_id
  t.string :relatee_type
end
```

And the model

```
class TaleRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :relater, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :relatee, polymorphic: true

  after_create :create_inverse_relationship
  after_destroy :destroy_inverse_relationship

  def create_inverse_relationship
    self.class.find_or_create_by(inverse_attributes)
  end

  def destroy_inverse_relationship
    self.class.find_by(inverse_attributes).try(:destroy)
  end

  def inverse_attributes
    {
      relater_id: relatee_id,
      relater_type: relatee_type,
      relatee_id: relater_id,
      relatee_type: relater_type
    }
  end
end
```

What I'm doing with the callbacks is every time you create or destroy a TaleRelation with a given relater and relatee, it creates or destroys the corresponding inverse. So if a given Tale is related to a Character, it follows that the Character is also related to the Tale. If you don't want this symmetry, just take those callbacks out.

Now, for example, in Tale:

```
class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tale_relations, as: :relater, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :characters, through: :tale_relations, source: :relatee, source_type: "Character"
  has_many :values, through: :tale_relations, source: :relatee, source_type: "Value"
  # and so on
end
```

And similar things in Value and Character and so on. Now a Tale has_many :characters without needing to store their ids as a comma-separated String or an Array as it looks like you were doing above in your table. Make sure not to include any self-referential has_many statements (i.e. don't put `has_many :characters` in Character)

So we define the relationship to TaleRelation via the polymorphic relater_id and relater_type, so we can have all these relationships without all the columns. And through this relationship we can gather (polymorphically!) all the relatees of the correct class. This gives me:

```
2.2.2 > t = Tale.create(name: "T")
 => #<Tale id: 1, name: "T">
2.2.2 > c = Character.create(name: "C")
 => #<Character id: 1, name: "C">
2.2.2 > d = Character.create(name: "D")
 => #<Character id: 2, name: "D">
2.2.2 > v = Value.create(name: "V")
 => #<Value id: 1, name: "V">
2.2.2 > t.characters << c
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Character id: 1, name: "C">]>
2.2.2 > v.characters << c
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Character id: 1, name: "C">]>
2.2.2 > v.characters << d
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Character id: 1, name: "C">, #<Character id: 2, name: "D">]>
2.2.2 > d.values
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Value id: 1, name: "V">]>
2.2.2 > t.characters.first.values
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Value id: 1, name: "V">]>
```

Note that this does NOT propagate second-order relationships. I.e.,

```
2.2.2 > t.values
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

even though t has a Character with a Value. Once you start doing that, pretty soon you'll have everything related to everything else.